# Azure Devops Git Tags no being listed via powershell API call

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, git-tag

I have an azure devops git Repo

If i browse to my Repos>>Tags I see a whole bunch of tags listed

[image]

I generate the tags is as follows

```
$rn= $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$sv = $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$project = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI
$projectName = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
$repo = $env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME

$repoUri = "$project/$projectName/_apis/git/repositories/$repo"

$request = @{}
$request.name = $rn
$request.message = $rn
$request.taggedObject = @{}
$request.taggedObject.objectId = $sv

$body = $request | ConvertTo-Json
$tagsUri = "$repoUri/annotatedtags?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$header = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $token" }

 $result = (Invoke-WebRequest $tagsUri -Method "Post" -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing).Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The tags get generated but when i click on them i get the following error
[image]

When i try to query the tags via API, i do not get the expected tags back that are listed in the UI

```
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
$uri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI
$project = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
$repo = $env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME
$gitUri = "$uri/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repo"
$gitHeader = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $token" }

$tagsUri = "$gitUri/refs/tags?api-version=5.1-preview.1&" + '$top=1000'
$tagsResult = (Invoke-WebRequest $tagsUri -Headers $gitHeader -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing).Content | ConvertFrom-Json

If($tagsResult.value.length -ne 0) {
    # get the Last 2 TAGS 
    $lastTag = $tagsResult.value[$tagsResult.value.length - 2]
    $lastTagHash = $lastTag.objectId

    $annotatedTagUri = "$gitUri/annotatedtags/" + $lastTagHash + "?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
    $annotatedTagsResult = (Invoke-WebRequest $annotatedTagUri -Headers $gitHeader -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing).Content | ConvertFrom-Json

    # get the Last Git Tag Hash
    $commitHash = $annotatedTagsResult.taggedObject.objectId
}
```

I am not sure if i am missing something in my logic or i am doing it wrong

Comment: dont see anything wrong with the way you create the tag. what response are you getting?

Comment: it does not return the last two tag i created,  $lastTag = $tagsResult.value[$tagsResult.value.length - 2]

Comment: why do you think you are creating two tags? do you get an HTTP 20x response?

Comment: No the tag gets created, i thought there might be something wrong with the tag as when i click on it i get the error above

Comment: Here I agree with 4c74356b41's opinion. No problem on your powershell script. The error message more relevant with you against the item security. Did you ever checked the **Network** from **F12** when you click on the tag but failed with error? If possible, I very hope you could share it here by covering some sensitive info.